# Options to create site columns on VS pointing to managed metadata term sets

Tags: managed-metadata

Lets say I have a feature that creates site columns. See code below

1. How do I make it managed metadata pointing to the right term set?
2. I need a way that its easy to install acrosss all environments and that I dont need to manually set the binding or create the term values.

   ```
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
       <Field
      ID="{a3e07dad-1d6f-4395-9b08-e2e56407c0d8}"
       Name="xxx_Domain"
       StaticName="xxx_Domain"
       DisplayName="$Resources:xxx.projectbname,sitecolumns_domain_displayName;"
       Type="Text"
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="$Resources:xxx.projectname,sitecolumns_fieldgroup;">
       </Field>
     </Elements>
   ```

Comment: there is code in there, but I need a moderator, cause cant see it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a feature receiver.

For each field we can then call a method like this one in the Feature Activated event:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Bind a Taxonomy Field Site Column to a specific TermSet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="taxonomyFieldId">The ID of the taxonomy field</param>
        /// <param name="taxonomyNoteFieldId">The ID of the Note field associated with the taxonomy field</param>
        /// <param name="termSetName">The TermSet name</param>
        /// <param name="termGroup">The name of the TermGroup</param>
        /// <param name="web">The root web of the site column</param>
        private void BindTaxonomyField(string taxonomyFieldId, string taxonomyNoteFieldId, string termSetName, string termGroup, SPWeb web)
        {
            if (web != null)
            {
                // get the taxonomyfield from the sitecollection
                TaxonomyField field = web.Fields[new Guid(taxonomyFieldId)] as TaxonomyField;
                if (field != null)
                {
                    // attach the note field
                    field.TextField = new Guid(taxonomyNoteFieldId);

                    // set up the field for my termstore
                    TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(web.Site);

                    if (session.TermStores.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // get termstore values
                        TermStore ts = session.TermStores[0];
                        Group group = GetGroup(termGroup, ts);
                        if (group == null)
                            throw new Exception("Group was not found in the termstore");
                        TermSet termSet = group.TermSets[termSetName];

                        // actually setup the field for using the TermStore
                        field.SspId = ts.Id;
                        field.TermSetId = termSet.Id;
                    }

                    field.Update();
                }
            }
        }

private Group GetGroup(string name, TermStore ts)
    {
        Group g = null;
        foreach (Group group in ts.Groups)
        {
            if (group.Name == name)
            {
                g = group;
                break;
            }
        }
        return g;
    }
```

Called like this (if web scoped feature):

```
BindTaxonomyField("f082aaa6-b70b-418c-a77e-41b19e0c064a", "23F8F82E-2C22-4F6D-B2C6-F4F76DE48A74", "TheTermSet", "TheTermGroup", properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb);
```

Your Site Columns XML should look like this:

```
<Field
   ID="{f082aaa6-b70b-418c-a77e-41b19e0c064a}"
   Name="TheName"
   StaticName="TheName"
   DisplayName="TheName"
   Type="TaxonomyFieldType"
   Required="FALSE"
   Group="AGroup" 
   Mult="FALSE"
   DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" 
   Overwrite="TRUE" />
  <Field Type="Note"
    DisplayName="TheName_0"
    StaticName="TheNameTaxHTField0"
    Name="TheNameTaxHTField0"
    ID="{23F8F82E-2C22-4F6D-B2C6-F4F76DE48A74}"
    Hidden="TRUE"
    DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
     />
```

Comment: is my xmlgood?, do I need more? or change something ! please let me know.

Comment: I have written a valid and working XML for a TaxonomyField above. The one in your question is for a Text Column..

Comment: please poste the code of the GetGFroup method

Comment: Sorry, now it's there